# LightFM train_interactions shared among train and test sets: This will cause incorrect evaluation, check your data split

Tags: python, recommendation-engine, lightfm

tl;dr: Working with Yelp Dataset to make a recommendation System but running into **Test interactions matrix and train interactions matrix share 68 interactions. This will cause incorrect evaluation, check your data split.** error when running the following LightFM code.

```
test_auc = auc_score(model,
                    test,
                    #train_interactions=train, #Unable to run with this line uncommented
                    item_features=sparse_features_matrix,
                    num_threads=NUM_THREADS).mean()
print('Hybrid test set AUC: %s' % test_auc)
```

---

Full Story: Working with Yelp Dataset to build a recommendation system.

Going off the code provided in example documentation (https://making.lyst.com/lightfm/docs/examples/hybrid_crossvalidated.html) for Hybrid Collaborative Filtering.

I ran my code the following way:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from lightfm import LightFM
from scipy import sparse
from lightfm.evaluation import auc_score

train, test = train_test_split(sparse_Rating_Matrix, test_size=0.25,random_state=4)
# Set the number of threads; you can increase this
# if you have more physical cores available.
NUM_THREADS = 2
NUM_COMPONENTS = 100
NUM_EPOCHS = 3
ITEM_ALPHA = 1e-6

# Define a new model instance
model = LightFM(loss='warp',
                item_alpha=ITEM_ALPHA,
                no_components=NUM_COMPONENTS)

# Fit the hybrid model. Note that this time, we pass
# in the item features matrix.
model = model.fit(train,
                item_features=sparse_features_matrix,
                epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                num_threads=NUM_THREADS)

# Don't forget the pass in the item features again!
train_auc = auc_score(model,
                      train,
                      item_features=sparse_features_matrix,
                      num_threads=NUM_THREADS).mean()
print('Hybrid training set AUC: %s' % train_auc)

test_auc = auc_score(model,
                    test,
                    #train_interactions=train, # Unable to run with this line uncommented
                    item_features=sparse_features_matrix,
                    num_threads=NUM_THREADS).mean()
print('Hybrid test set AUC: %s' % test_auc)
```

I had 2 problems:

1) Running the line in question uncommented (train_interactions=train) originally yielded **Inconsistent Shape**

which was resolved by the following:
"test" data set was modified by the following block of code to append a block of zeros below it until the dimensions match that of my train data set (per this recommendation: https://github.com/lyst/lightfm/issues/369):

```
#Add X users to Test so that the number of rows in Train match Test
N = train.shape[0] #Rows in Train set
n,m = test.shape #Rows & columns in Test set

z = np.zeros([(N-n),m]) #Create the necessary rows of zeros with m columns
test = test.todense() #Temporarily convert Test into a numpy array
test = np.vstack((test,z)) #Vertically stack Test on top of the blank users
test = sparse.csr_matrix(test) #Convert back to sparse
```

2) After the shape issue was resolved, I tried to implement "train_interactions=train"

But ran into **Test interactions matrix and train interactions matrix share 68 interactions. This will cause incorrect evaluation, check your data split.**

And I"m not sure how to resolve this 2nd issue. Any ideas?

Details:
-"sparse_features_matrix" is a sparse matrix of {items x categories} where if an item was "Italian" and "Pizza" then the category of "Italian" and "Pizza" would have a value "1" for that item's row ... "0" elsewhere. 
-"sparse_Rating_Matrix" is a sparse matrix of {users x items} containing values of the user's ratings to the restaurant (item).

04/08/2020 Update: 
LightFM has a whole Database() class object that you should use to prep your data set prior to model evaluation. I found a great github post (https://github.com/lyst/lightfm/issues/494) where user Med-ELOMARI provides an amazing walk through on a small test data set.

When I prepped my data through this method, I was able to add in user_features that I wanted to model (E.g: User_1592 likes "Thai","Mexican","Sushi" cuisines).

Per Turbo's comment, I used LightFM's random_train_test_split method (had originally split my data via sklearn's train_test_split method) and ran the auc_score with the new train/test sets AND the correctly (as far as im aware) prepared model I still run into the same error code:

Input:

```
%%time
(train,test) = random_train_test_split(lightfm_interactions,test_percentage=0.25) #LightFM's method to split
# Don't forget the pass in the item features again!
train_auc = auc_score(model_users,
                      train,
                      user_features=lightfm_user_features_list,
                      num_threads=NUM_THREADS).mean()
print('User_feature training set AUC: %s' % train_auc)

test_auc = auc_score(model_users,
                    test,
                    #train_interactions=train, #Still can't get this to function
                    user_features=lightfm_user_features_list,
                    num_threads=NUM_THREADS).mean()
print('User_feature test set AUC: %s' % test_auc)
```

Output if "train_interactions=train" is used:

```
ValueError: Test interactions matrix and train interactions matrix share 435 interactions. This will cause incorrect evaluation, check your data split.
```

Good news however is --- by switching from sklearn's train_test_split to LightFM's random_train_test_split my model's AUC score went from 0.49 to 0.96 on training. So I guess it's important to stick with LightFM's methods if available!

Comment: Hi. Did you ever end up figuring this out? I'm having the same issue and am using the random_train_test_split method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I decided to just forego the "train_interactions=train" line command that was giving me a headache.


As noted in the update on 08Apr20 -- It seems LightFM has its own datatype for `data` objects and you might benefit from building your dataset within LightFM's structure instead of something like SciKitLearn.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. I was using the lightfm methods to format and input the data and was still getting the same error.

Comment: @user2382321, hello, I am also facing the same error, have you figured it out?

Answer (score 2):

LightFM provide a way of splitting your dataset, did you look on it?
With it, it might work.
https://making.lyst.com/lightfm/docs/cross_validation.html

Comment: Hi, I think the problem I had was .. i followed the example exactly as written but it turns out LightFM has a whole Database() class object which preps data to work in its package. After prepping my data through Database.fit(), Database.build_interactions(),  Database.build_user_features() ... I was able to finally get some results from the package. (However I never came back to revisit this train_interactions method in auc_score -- let me try that again)

Comment: Nope, i used the LightFM method for random_train_test_split() and also fed in the new interaction matrix generated from "(fm_interactions,weights) = Database.build_interactions(yelp_interactions)" where yelp_interactions is a list of tuples, (user_id,item_id,rating), into auc_score(...,train_interaction=fm_interactions,...) but got the same "Test interactions matrix and train interactions matrix share 391 interactions. This will cause incorrect evaluation, check your data split." error message I got previously

Comment: @Shyu, have you solved the share interaction issues? I am also facing the issue now..